# Chrome driver issue in PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While executing the script in PAF , I am getting error message as

> 'chrome driver doesn't support the chrome version'

. How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the compatible chromedriver.exe file in drivers folder

Before replacing the latest driver in drivers folder, End Task for chromedriver.exe in Task Manager.